# How to test redux-form using react-testing-library

Tags: redux-form, react-testing-library

I'm trying to test a code that is a part of redux-form using react-testing-library. Calling fireEvent.change for text input fields to set up new values I expect that input's values should be updated, but it never happens. Please find a fragment of the test below. Full code can be found at https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-form-simple-example-n3820
Any good examples how to test redux-form using react-testing-library?

...

```
const firstNameInput = getByTestId(container, "firstName");
const lastNameInput = getByTestId(container, "lastName");

const firstName = "firstName";
const lastName = "lastName";

fireEvent.change(firstNameInput, { target: { value: firstName } });
fireEvent.change(lastNameInput, { target: { value: lastName } });

const submitButton = getByTestId(container, "submitButton");
fireEvent.click(submitButton);

expect(onSubmit).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
expect(onSubmit).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(firstName, lastName);
```

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Is it solved?

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you are doing `fireEvent.click(submitButton)` which fires a `click` event on the button. Your form is not listening for that event though, it's listening for the submit event on the form. You have to do this instead `fireEvent.submit(formElement)`.

---

Some other things I noticed that are not necessarily wrong but could be better.

There's no need to import `getByTestId` you get it back from the `render`:

```
// Before
import { render, getByTestId } from '@testing-library/react'
const { container } = render(<Component />)
getByTestId(container, 'foo')

// After
import { render } from '@testing-library/react'
const { getByTestId } = render(<Component />)
getByTestId('foo')
```

---

Speaking of `getByTestId` you should use it as a last resort. In your case, it's much better to use `getByLabelText` to get the inputs and `getByText` to find the button. To get the `form` you can use `getByText('Submit').closest('form')`.

---

You should use the [`cleanup`](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api#cleanup) method to avoid issues in your tests.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I've updated tests to use form submit instead of button click, but still cannot get the tests passed. Please find the updated version here https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-form-simple-example-po8bx  It looks like that values of text fields are not updated after fireEvent.change for them.

Comment: I think the error you're seeing is related to codesandbox https://github.com/codesandbox/codesandbox-client/issues/502

Comment: Run your tests in your local machine and you should see the correct issue

Comment: Tests failed on the local machine as well.

Comment: The same error, the test fails because inputs' values were not updated after fireEvent.change, so form onSubmit was called with initial input values not with updated https://imgur.com/a/Q6aL7hh

Comment: @GiorgioPolvara-Gpx Could you please rewrite your answer because it is not answering the question. The problem is about the `fireEvent.change` and the input field not updating.

Answer (score 3):

You have used `createMockStore` from `redux-test-utils`. It sure makes creating store easier. But the `redux form` should be connected to `redux store` to work.
You can read the documentation at:

https://redux-form.com/8.2.2/docs/gettingstarted.md/#overview
and
https://redux-form.com/8.2.2/docs/gettingstarted.md/#data-flow

I created the store following `react-testing-library` documentation to test redux
https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-redux

```
const renderWithRedux = (
  component,
  {
    initialState,
    store = createStore(
      combineReducers({ userReducer, form: formReducer }),
      initialState
    )
  } = {}
) => {
  return {
    ...render(<Provider store={store}>{component}</Provider>)
  };
};
```

I too was facing the same problem as yours. So, the test I have created is different than yours but the problem here is same (i.e form is not being filled with `redux-form`)

Here is the link to codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-greider-4gqcg